# Slow upload to Server 2008 DC, Downloads work as expected

Tags: networking, latency

I have a Windows Server 2008 Domain Controller that I run as a do-it-all server. It has a GbE connection to the network and to every machine on the network.

Downloads from the server file shares work as expected, between 70MB/s and 80MB/s to all the machines. However, when I try to copy files back up to the server, speeds fall to 7MB/s-10MB/s. I've disabled flow control and large send offload properties on all the NICs.

I had this problem before and managed to fix it through some properties changes, but like an idiot, I never documented my fix and have since moved to a new server.

Any ideas what I need to do to get the speeds to be more symmetric?

EDIT: Remote differential compression is also disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have a duplex mismatch, aka server is negotiating at 1GB but switch is negotiating at say 100Mbit.

Worth a check on the advanced settings of the network card.

Worth a look: http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/01/08/configuring-advanced-network-card-settings-in-windows-server-2008-server-core.aspx